# Printing int variables with float format specifier

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, floating-point, printf

```
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    float b=7.5;

    printf("%d %f\n",a,b);
    printf("%d %f\n",a,a);

    return 0;
}
```

when i compile this in gcc compiler output is

```
5 7.500000
5 7.500000
```

But when in visual studio, output is

```
5 7.500000
5 0.000000
```

I am not able to understand gcc compiler output.

Comment: gcc *might* take the last float given...

Comment: If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Why visual studio output result int a as a float is "0.0000000" ?

Comment: I would guess that gcc's output is because it passes floating point arguments to `printf` in floating point registers, while integers are passed in general purpose registers, and the last thing that was in that floating point register before `printf("%d %f\n",a,a);` was `b`.

Comment: @VBB How gcc takes last float?

Comment: @Charles0429 because you printed it as a float. MohanMangal: it's a simple guess, i'm not sure of anything :)

Comment: @VBB a = 5, the output is "0.00000" while not "5.00000"?

Comment: @Charles0429 because VS seems to ignore a and display an empty float

Comment: As per @daniel-fischer Comment, floating point variables are taken from **floating point register** so `%f` will take last floating point variables which was `b`, But as per @kirilenko answer, it shall have undefined behavior as it will try to get a `double` of **sizeof(double)**. So what exactly happenning there? So these values are on stack or register?

Comment: @MohanMangal You use the wrong conversion specifier, so the behaviour **is undefined**. I was just making a guess as to what actually happened in this case (even if the behaviour is undefined, _something_ will happen). How the arguments (in general, and to `printf` in particular) are passed is ABI-dependent. On x86_64 (at least Linux, don't know about Windows), the first arguments for `printf` are passed in registers, the stack is only used if there are too many arguments to place them all in registers. On x86 (32-bit), the (all `printf`) arguments are passed on the stack, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` prototype is:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

#### C11 (n1570), § 6.5.2.2 Function calls

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.**

#### C11 (n1570), § 6.5.2.2 Function calls

> the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument
>   promotions.

Therefore, no other argument promotion is performed with a `printf` call. In particular, `a` is not converted to `double`. Hence it will result in a undefined behavior: `printf` will try to get a `double` with a given size (`sizeof(double)`) and a given memory representation, which could be different from an `int`.

#### C11 (n1570), § 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Besides, you can look at the ASM code generated by *gcc* to see what is going on.